# Exception on extracting a zipfile, after appending to it in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-zipfile

```
z = zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(artifact), mode='a') 
z.write("test.txt",arcname=r'bin/test.txt')
z.extractall('out')
```

> Exception:
>   zipfile.BadZipFile was unhandled by user code
>   Message: File name in directory 'bin\test.txt' and header b'bin/test.txt' differ.

The interesting thing is if I write the file to disk, and try extract it, I get a invalid file error. This is on Win 7 by the way.
the bin folder already exists in the zipfile. [Full Traceback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mM2qK.jpg)

Comment: Please supply the FULL trace-back, Please explain what the `io.BytesIO(artifact)` is all about. The `bin` folder already exists where? The question header indicates the exception is raised when writing, but the question body points at `extractall`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the code works well on my Mac,and I think you should let us know that the structure of the zip file or what the variable `artifact` is.

Here is my advice:

- Use forward slashes as path separators,when you create the zip file.
- Try to print a warning not raise the exception,and check out the `out` folder,you will find the reason,maybe the slashes or string buffer.

Also you can read this [issue](http://bugs.python.org/issue6839).

Hope this helps.